Use of GaussianBlurEffect in Winui 3 and CommunityToolkit.WINUUI.UI version 8
How can use GaussianBlurEffect in WINUI 3 and CommunityToolkit.WINUI,UI versione 8?
public static CompositionEffectBrush CreateBlurEffectBrush(double amount = 0.0)
{
    var effect = new GaussianBlurEffect
    {
        Name = "Blur",
        BlurAmount = (float)amount,
        Source = new CompositionEffectSourceParameter("source")
    };

    var compositor = App.MainWindow.Compositor;
    var factory = compositor.CreateEffectFactory(effect as IGraphicsEffect, new[] { "Blur.BlurAmount" }); // Cast to IGraphicsEffect
    var brush = factory.CreateBrush();
    brush.SetSourceParameter("source", compositor.CreateBackdropBrush());
    return brush;
}


Do you mean the BlurEffectAnimation from the CommunityToolkit?

I need to convert the code from UWP to WINUI3

Did you check the SceneGraph sample?

You need to install the Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D NuGet package.
Then make the MainWindow accessible.
App.xaml.cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace WinUIApp;

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static Window MainWindow { get; } = new MainWindow();

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        MainWindow.Activate();
    }
}


Thanks for the help, I solved it thanks to you

If it helped, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session.

According to the issue, https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsCompositionSamples/issues/218, GaussianBlurEffect is supported, also in Composition. For applying brushes to XAML content, see the SceneGraph sample.
